# "Being a kid, I was afraid ..." - Does the participle imply "when" or "because"?

Tags: phrase-meaning

What does this sentence with the present participle mean?

> Being a kid, I was afraid of dogs.

Does it mean

> When I was a kid, I was afraid of dogs.

or

> Because I was a kid, I was afraid of dogs.

?

Comment: It means the second, but the first is implied.

Answer (score 1):

> Because/As I was a kid, I was afraid of dogs.

This is the correct interpretation.